# IPV6 Curl POST request

Tags: post, curl, ipv6

In IPV6 how to build CURL POST http request with the IPV6 address and port number.Any kind of thread will be appreciated.

Tried to build the request as below

```
>curl --interface 'http://[2001:0:db8:1111:0:0:0:11]:8091/?'
```

But above gave error as "curl: NO URL specified"

```
>curl -X POST -d  curl -X POST `http://[2001:0:db8:1111:0:0:0:11]:8091/?`
```

Then tried the above that gave error as

```
>bash: http://[2001:0:db8:1111:0:0:0:11]:8091/?: No such file or directory
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Is there any alternate method, other than using URL

Answer (score 10):

```
curl -g -d post 'http://[2001:0:db8:1111:0:0:0:11]:8091/'
```

The [-g](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-g) option was necessary "back in the old days" when you used IPv6 addresses. It stops curl from treating the [] symbols in the URL as globbing instructions. (*since curl 7.37.0 (May 2014), curl no longer mistakes numerical IPv6 addresses for globbing, making the use of -g in this case no longer necessary*)

The -d is of course for posting. You can slap on a -v too to get to see details from the operation.

(And no, `-X POST` should not be in the command line at all when `-d` is used.)

Comment: Apparently in 2018 the `-g` is still needed - `curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.34 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3`.

Comment: No, you mean you needed in [2013](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_29_0). I think that qualifies as "in the old days".

Comment: While the keyword 'post' in the command should be upper-case:  curl -g -d POST 'http://[2001:0:db8:1111:0:0:0:11]:8091/'

Answer (score 3):

`curl -4` for an IPv4 request and
`curl -6` for an IPv6 request are the arguments, that you can use.

For your examle, this should work:

`curl -6 -d post 'http://2001:0:db8:1111:0:0:0:11:8091/'`

Answer (score 0):

Win10:

curl **-X** POST http://[fe80::a989:2147:5f46:a4f3%4]:58080 **-H** "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" **-d** "username=xxx&pd=xxxx&..."
[image]

---

-X, --request: HTTP method for communicating with the server.

-H, --header: HTTP headers to send to the server with POST request.

-d, --data: Data to be sent to the server using a POST request in the form of key/value pairs.