# Fail to deploy Angular with Docker and Nginx on AWS EC2

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

Here is the structure of Docker folder:

```
.
├── default.conf
├── dist
│   ├──3rdpartylicenses.txt
│   ├──favicon.ico
│   ├──index.html
│   ├──main.814148b8a52c3996d8f6.js
│   ├──polyfills.c72d3210425a88b28b6d.js
│   ├──runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js
│   └──styles.914f038ddd792d8e3589.css
└── Dockerfile
```

The content of `default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

The content of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The files in `dist` are from `ng build --prod`.

So I execute the command: `docker build -t nanda_image .` on ec2 ssh. And then `docker run --rm --name nanda_container -p 80:80 nanda_image`.

This is the result from `docker container ls`:

[image]

Output of `netstat -nlp`:

[image]

After this, I consider I finish deployment. At least, I believe. However, when I try to access the website I deploy, what I got is that the IP took too long to respond. Really want to know where is the mistake. Thank you all. :)

Comment: Please create a EC2 security group and assign to the server where you run the docker container if you haven't done so already. Add -d option to your docker run command as well.  `docker run -d --rm --name nanda_container -p 80:80 nanda_image`

Comment: Are you able to access this website right from the EC2? i.e. running `curl localhost`

Comment: @RobertRanjan I am trying to figure out how to create the security group using ssh since I don't have a password which allowed me to directly login to the ec2. All I have is a .pem key. Will let you know if this works. Thank you!

Comment: @IgnacioMillán What I get is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`. Seems I fail to deploy... Still trying to figure out what happens... Really appreciate your answering!

Comment: About security groups, plese refer to EC2 documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: @RobertRanjan @IgnacioMillán If I only have `.pem` file, does this mean I am not allowed to assign a security group to a server? I am trying to use `aws ec2` command, but I need `AWS Access Key ID` and `AWS Secret Access Key` to do so. All I can do now is to contact the guy who gives me the `.pem` file?

Comment: First make sure you created nginx successfully and can access it from your ssh terminal. Create container using command I provided above, see there is a `-d` flag added. Then run `curl localhost` and make sure nginx is running and accessible locally.

Comment: @RobertRanjan First, I want to thank you for your big patience. I use the detached mode you suggest and use `docker ps` to check the container is indeed running. However, when I tried to `curl localhost`, what it provide is `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`. Does this mean that the problem is not on the security group issue but is on Nginx itself?

Comment: @RobertRanjan Although the server is still not working, I updated the new Dockerfile to make more sense.

Comment: I just created files & folders the way your have, built docker image, ran container and accessed the page using curl and browser. Not sure why is not working for you. Can you attach screen shot of `docker run ...` and `netstat -nlp` output to your question?

Comment: I do not see any issue with older or newer Dockerfile, both works fine. Please add above details to your question.

Comment: @RobertRanjan I have attached the screen shot. Thank you for your help! For `tcp 127.0.0.1:5002` is just a python restful API running with `tmux`. I think it is not relative but just in case.

Comment: Thanks. Port 80 is listening but not sure why is it `tcp6` instead of `tcp`.  Try curl as per this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302447/ipv6-curl-post-request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172094/discussion-between-robert-ranjan-and-mars-lee).